# Positioning a span next to an image secondary image label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like the secondary label to be right under "Image Label". Currently it is all the way at the bottom.

I am forcing the secondary label to be under using a line break and then moving it to the right using margin-left. I don't think this is the way to go at all and I tried using margin bottom which will not move the element up.

What is the best way to achieve this using CSS? My code for current result is here: https://codepen.io/codeAligned/pen/gOOByOa

Current:

[image: <code>sample-image-kiplinger</code>]

Desired:

[image]

```css
.post-container {

  width: 75%;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 64px;
  padding-top: 64px;

  article {
    header {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 32px;

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: color 0.3s ease;

        &:focus {
          text-decoration: none;
          text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
        }

        &:active {
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        &:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }



    .avatar {
      margin: 16px auto;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}


.bg-img-hero {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  margin-right: 25px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


.transition-3d-hover {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.transition-3d-hover:hover,
.transition-3d-hover:focus {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.story-image {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  align-self: center;

  img {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

.post-avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.article-avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tag-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.avatar-container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

.subtitle-container {
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-color: lightgray;
  min-height: 100px;
}


.subtitle-date {
  padding-left: 80px;
}


.subtitle-body {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.label-position {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtitle">
  <div class="subtitle-container">
    <div class="article-avatar rounded-circle sb-avatar" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 60px; height: 60px; font-family: Helvetica;">
      <img class="article-avatar rounded-circle sb-avatar__image" width="60px" height="60px" src="https://www.kiplinger.com/slideshow/spending/T062-S001-things-millennials-are-changing-forever/images/intro.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
    
    <span class="subtitle-body font-size-1 ml-3">
  Image label
      <br/>
      <small class="label-position">secondary label</small>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a few display options . https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYYmXLX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using flexbox for these things. You can go through https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Here your code with quick fix

```css
.subtitle-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;  
}

.subtitle-container >div{
    padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="subtitle">
  <div class="subtitle-container">
    <div class="article-avatar rounded-circle sb-avatar" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; width: 60px; height: 60px; font-family: Helvetica;">

      <img class="article-avatar rounded-circle sb-avatar__image" width="60px" height="60px" src="https://www.kiplinger.com/slideshow/spending/T062-S001-things-millennials-are-changing-forever/images/intro.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
    
    <div>
    <span class="subtitle-body font-size-1 ml-3">
  Image label
      <br/>
      <small class="label-position">secondary label</small>
    </span>
      
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With flex you do

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    // your image here
  </div>
  <div class="label">
    <div><span>Image label</span></div>
    <div><small>Secondary label</small></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add your css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

The default direction is `row` so `div`s inside `.container` will stand next to each other while the `div`s inside `.label` will stack on each other because `div` is a block element